# Event to sort by a column

Tags: datatable, primefaces

I've a `<p:datatable>` with sortable columns. I would like obtaining the event when click on header in any column.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What Primefaces version?? Maybe it would be for the best to create two different primefaces tags (2 and 3)...

About your solution...you know that `DataTable has built-in support for ajax sorting.` Means that every sort would be an ajax request, so you could intercept this ajax call. A solution to do that would be to implement an `ajax status component` that `on start`, or `on complete` to call a javascript function or a server side method...

Here you can find the ajax status: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/ajaxStatusHome.jsf